# QField - how to show features list in alphabetical order?

Tags: qgis, features, qfield, list

I created a project in QGIS and synced it to QField.  When I ask qfield to show a features list of a point layer from the project the names are not in alphabetical order.  Is there a way to alphabetize the list each time that I open it? I have tried to renumber the fid field and resync project but that did not seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is being addressed and solved [in this enhancement](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/pull/4192),
you will have to download the APK mentioned in the link.

When preparing the layer in QGIS to export to QField, a sorting expression has to be defined in the feature list, or else QField will fallback to sorting features by fid.

I have tried it and it worked!